# adding whole total using javascript

Tags: javascript, addition

```
function total()
{
    var tot = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        var total_id = "total_" + i;
        tot = tot + document.getElementById(total_id).value;
    }
    document.getElementById(total).value = tot;
}
```

"this code should display total; i have several total_i id to display my total in each row. then i have display that row total to my total named form"

Answer (score 2):

`tot = tot + document.getElementById(total_id).value;`

Note that the `value` of an element is a string, so `+` here is a string concatenation, not addition (for example, `1 + 1 = 11`)

If you want to do addition (`1 + 1 = 2`), use

`tot = tot + parseInt(document.getElementById(total_id).value);`

Answer (score 0):

you can replace your code line `tot = tot + document.getElementById(total_id).value;` 
with: `tot = tot + parseInt(document.getElementById(total_id).value);` as the javascript is taking it as a string not a integr value. We can convert it to integer by using parseInt().

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem, as mentioned in another answer, is that you're adding strings, specifically the `value` property on a DOM element which is a string. You'll find any number of questions on SO about that.

If you have the elements in an array, finding the sum just becomes

```
function add(a, b) { return a + b; }
function sum(array) { return array.reduce(add); }

sum(elements.map(function(elt) { return +elt.value; });
```

However, you're also using the anti-pattern of using ID's as a poor-man's way of identifying and referring to DOM elements. It's better just to remember the elements themselves as you create and add them (if in fact that's how they're being created). That way, you don't have to spend the rest of live constructing IDs and adding them to elements and then constructing them again to pass to  `getElementById` to find them again. By "remembering the elements themselves as you create them", I mean instead of doing something like this:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    var elt = document.createElement('div');
    elt.setAttribute('id', 'total_' + i);
    parent.appendChild(elt);
}
```

or the equivalent in jQuery, do something like

```
var elements = [];
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    var elt = document.createElement('div');
    elements.push(elt);
    parent.appendChild(elt);
}
```

Now you have the array of elements themselves, and you don't have to poking around with `getElementById` every time you want to access them.